# Android fragment textview.settext with button click

Tags: android, textview, fragment

I have a problem with **Textview in Fragment**. In my fragment xml, I have `ImageButtons` and `TextView`. I want that if I click the button, the `Textview` to change. I do everything as usual but it crashes.

Here is my code:

```
    public class Tatlilar extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener{


    public Tatlilar() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_tatlilar, container, false);
        ImageButton imageButtonKalsonuc = (ImageButton) view.findViewById(R.id.imageButtonCikolata);
        final TextView textViewKalsonuc = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textViewSonuc);

        imageButtonKalsonuc.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"tıklandı", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                textViewKalsonuc.setText("hello");
            }
        });
        return view;

    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
    }
}
```

here is my error log:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main                                                                              
                                                                           java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void   android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference
                                                                              at com.azelirbrevo.glisemikindeks.Tatlilar$1.onClick(Tatlilar.java:44)
                                                                              at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4756)
                                                                              at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19761)
                                                                              at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                                              at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                              at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5253)
                                                                              at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                              at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
                                                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
```

my xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<TableLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="350dp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="false"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="false"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="false"
    android:gravity="left"
    android:layout_marginTop="70dp"
    android:id="@+id/tableLayout">

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <ImageButton android:id="@+id/imageButtonCikolata"
            android:layout_column="3"
            android:src="@drawable/chocolate"
            android:background="@null"
            android:layout_width="70dp"
            android:layout_height="70dp"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:layout_marginLeft="15dp" />

     <LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="420dp">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:id="@+id/textViewKaloriSonuc"
        android:textAlignment="center" />
```

Comment: Post the error log that you are getting , and your question isn't clear what you wanna ask.

Comment: That is because, you textView is  null

Comment: Since you didn't post the error log or the layout, either your textview is getting the wrong id and is null or the imagebutton is

Comment: If you post you crash log then we can help,

Comment: I added the error log now.

Comment: Add your xml file too

Comment: id of your textview may not be right one , cross check id and layout file nbame

Comment: yep. that was my mistake. thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> You have given wrong id to `Text View`. Your `xml` file contains different id then which you used.
>
> Change this.

```
TextView textViewKalsonuc = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textViewSonuc);
```

> To this.

```
TextView textViewKalsonuc = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textViewKaloriSonuc);
```